# How to set a default open window size and window location for vlc and chrome in gnome?

Tags: centos-8

Is it possible to open vlc/chrome with a custom window size and window location in Linux and set those values as a default every time i open them.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily resize and move the windows, but I am not sure about automating it.

**For the resizing / moving part:**

If you have not, install xdotools:

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install xdotool -y
```

Search your application's ID:

id = `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name vlc`

```
xdotool windowsize $id $WIDTH $HEIGHT
xdotool windowmove $id $X $Y
```

e.g.

```
xdotool windowsize 197 600 400
xdotool windowmove 197 960 540
```

**Automation:**

For how to automate the process I have never tried. I see two potential solutions either you create a cron job (inefficient but should work pretty easily) or try to play with Chrome's JS. The creation of a window should create an event to which a Listener might be able to respond by launching the script above.

Hope it helps!